# When to use dereferencing pointers

Tags: go, pointers

I am currently learning Go.

Following this [link](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy/go/example#example-0--cache-go). On `initCache` function it accepts a `evictionAlgo` type parameter without `*` prefix so meaning it's not the pointer. See below the code I am referring.

```golang
type cache struct {
    storage      map[string]string
    evictionAlgo evictionAlgo
    capacity     int
    maxCapacity  int
}

func initCache(e evictionAlgo) *cache {
    storage := make(map[string]string)
    return &cache{
        storage:      storage,
        evictionAlgo: e,
        capacity:     0,
        maxCapacity:  2,
    }
}
```

I got really confused. So my question is when or what scenario to consider when using a dereference pointer? And when should I not use dereference.

Comment: It depends upon use.

Comment: A rule of thumb applies to `evictionAlgo`: Don't use pointers to interface types.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense @CeriseLimón thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you only have two situations where you would use a pointer as input or output. For output, I don't think it's ever really needed. My use case for it, it just as a convenience. Normally if you are returning an empty `struct`, you might do it like this:

```
package user
import "os"

type cache struct { dir string }

func newCache() (cache, error) {
   c, e := os.UserCacheDir()
   if e != nil {
      return cache{}, e
   }
   return cache{c}, nil
}
```

but if you instead change to pointer, then you can use `nil` for the zero value:

```
func newCache() (*cache, error) {
   c, e := os.UserCacheDir()
   if e != nil { return nil, e }
   return &cache{c}, nil
}
```

Regarding input, you should only need a pointer, if you need to change a field:

```
package user

type cache struct { dir string }

func (c *cache) set() {
   c.dir = "north"
}
```

I thought you could change a slice or `map` field without a pointer receiver, but upon trying it only seems to work with pointer receiver as well.